# How to call a function defined as a string?

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I want to define functions and scripts in a database record then using Javascript convert the database field from a string to code.

I was thinking I could use 'eval', but this doesn't seem to work.

As an example:

```
    var strTest = "function(strParams) { alert('hello: ' + strParams); };"
       ,fn = eval(strTest);
    fn("World");
```

This doesn't work, eval returns undefined, hopefully this gives the idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Check out [the `Function()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `eval` parses your function as a function declaration. But function declarations require a name.

Instead, you should make it a function expression, which doesn't require one.

```
var strTest = "(function(strParams) { alert('hello: ' + strParams); })";
eval(strTest)("World");
```

Only do this if you trust the string.

Alternatively, you may be interested in the `Function` constructor:

```
var f = Function("strParams", "alert('hello: ' + strParams)");
f("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<script src="http://my-server/js-func/foobar.js"></script>
```

and have the server serve up the JS retrieved from the DB at that endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, however I prefer the solution as I have it with the content in the database.

Comment: Fine. Just in case I wasn't clear, I **was** suggesting leaving the content in the database. I was just proposing that it could be served as a JS document in response to a request on a particular endpoint. Upon receiving the request, the server would retrieve the code from the database, then serve it, this allows the client to think of the code as a kind of "virtual" JS file, and leaves the parsing/execution up to the normal client-side `<script>` tag mechanisms without having to worry about `eval` or `Function`.